# How to change font color of labels react-chartjs-2 with V4.3.1

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Having trouble with adding font color to black in the react chart js library

[chatjs data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i7sT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to change the font color of the tick labels, this can be done through the axes `ticks` configuration as follows.

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
    y: {
      ticks: {
        color: 'black'
      }
    }
  }
};

...

<Bar options={options} data={data} />;
```

> For further details, please consult [Tick Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration) from the Chart.js documentation

Comment: What about the fontsize?